# Why do these selectors fail for ExtJS ComboBox in this.control()?

Tags: extjs, combobox, css-selectors

I have the following 2 components in a field set in a view file on a form.

```
Ext.define('App.view.prospects.Filter', {
    alias:                             'widget.prospectsfilter',
    extend:                            'Ext.form.Panel',
    itemId:                            'prospectsfilter', 

...

initComponent:                      function(){

...

this.testButton = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {     
        handler:                    function() {this.fireEvent('testEvent')},
        iconCls:                   'icon-apply_16x16',
        itemId:                    'testButton',
        text:                      'Test'
    });

this.campaignsComboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        anchor:                    '100%',
        displayField:              'name',
        fieldLabel:                'Campaign(s)',
        itemId:                    'campaignsComboBox',
        labelWidth:                 90,
        listConfig:                 {
            minWidth:               150  
        },
        listeners:                  {
            select:                 function() {this.fireEvent('testEvent');}
        },
        multiSelect:                false,
        queryMode:                 'local',
        store:                      this.campaignsStore,
        value:                      null,
        valueField:                'id'
    });
```

Now, in the controller, I have:

```
Ext.define('App.controller.ProspectsFilter', {
    extend:                            'Ext.app.Controller',    
    models:                             ['Prospect'],
    stores:                             ['Prospects'],
    views:                              ['prospects.Filter'],

...

    init:                               function() {
        this.control({
           'prospectsfilter #testButton':{
                testEvent:              function(){console.log('Found #testButton!');}
           },

           'prospectsfilter #campaignsComboBox':{
                 testEvent:              function(){console.log('Found #campaignsComboBox!');}
        }
    }
});
```

When I click the 'testButton', I see the message in the console that it was found.

However, when I make a selection in the `campaignsComboBox`, nothing happens.

Why?

UPDATE:

The following is a good test, but fails to identify the root cause. I added other components to test, and events for the textfield are captured just fine. Others fail. Why?

Here is the updated controller:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.ProspectsFilter', {

extend:                            'Ext.app.Controller',

models:                             ['Prospect'],
stores:                             ['Prospects'],
views:                              ['prospects.Filter'],

init:                               function() {

    this.control({
        'prospectsfilter #campaignsComboBox' : {
            render:                 this.comboRender,
            select:                 this.comboSelect
        },
        'prospectsfilter #campaignsDateField' : {
            render:                 this.dateRender,
            select:                 this.dateSelect
        },
        'prospectsfilter #campaignsTextField' : {
            render:                 this.textRender,
            change:                 this.textChange
        }
    });

},

comboRender: function(combobox)  {console.log('comboRender');}, // Never executes.
comboSelect: function(combobox)  {console.log('comboSelect');}, // Never executes.
dateRender:  function(dateField) {console.log('dateRender'); }, // Never executes.
dateSelect:  function(dateField) {console.log('dateSelect'); }, // Never executes.
textRender:  function(textField) {console.log('textRender'); }, // Executes.
textChange:  function(textField) {console.log('textChange'); }  // Executes.
});
```

Here is the updated view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.prospects.Filter', {

alias:                             'widget.prospectsfilter',
extend:                            'Ext.form.Panel',
itemId:                            'prospectsfilter',

....

initComponent:                      function(){

    ....

    this.dateField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date',{
        fieldLabel:                'Date',
        itemId:                    'campaignsDateField'
    });

    this.textField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text',{
        fieldLabel:                'Text',
        itemId:                    'campaignsTextField'
    });

    this.campaignsComboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        anchor:                    '100%',
        displayField:              'name',
        fieldLabel:                'Campaign(s)',
        itemId:                    'campaignsComboBox',
        labelWidth:                 90,
        listConfig:                 {
            minWidth:               150  
        },
        multiSelect:                false,
        queryMode:                 'local',
        store:                      Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
            fields:                 ['name'],
            data:                   [['entry1'], ['entry2'], ['entry3']]
        }),
        tabindex:                   7,
        value:                      null,
        valueField:                'id'
    });

    this.statusToSegmentFieldSet = Ext.create('Ext.form.FieldSet', {
        anchor:                    '100%',
        autoHeight:                 true,
        collapsed:                  true,
        collapsible:                true,
        defaults:                   {
            editable:               false,
            forceSelection:         false
        },
        items:                      [                                   
            this.dateField,
            this.textField,
            this.campaignsComboBox
        ],
        layout:                    'anchor',
        margin:                    '10 10 10 10',
        title:                     'Dispositions, Campaigns, Segments'
    });

    .......

    var config = {        
        autoRender:                 true,
        autoScroll:                 true,
        bodyStyle:                 'background-color: #F1F1F1;',
        border:                     true,
        //buttons:                    [
        //    this.applyButton,
        //    this.clearButton
        //],
        collapsed:                  false,
        collapsible:                true,
        frame:                      true,
        height:                     200,
        items:                      [
            //this.datePicker,
            //this.dateRangeFieldSet,
            //this.prospectDetailsFieldSet,
            this.statusToSegmentFieldSet
            //this.assignedToFieldSet
        ],
        layout:                    'anchor',
        minWidth:                   300,
        region:                    'east',
        split:                      true,
        stateId:                   'prospectsModuleFilter',
        title:                     'Advanced Filters',
        width:                      300            
    };

    Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
    this.callParent(arguments);

}
});
```

UPDATE: Aug 28:

OK. I have narrowed it down further, to the point that I can reproduce the issue we are having in JSFiddle.

Hopefully, this will make it very easy for someone to help me figure out what is wrong.

Please read the note at JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4JubT/3/

Comment: edited my answer below, see my example.

Comment: the answer is don't add class-all with ext-all together.

Comment: The all-classes.js file is completely different from ext-all.js and the app we are working on is a desktop/webtop, so we need the all-classes.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the "select" event gets fired in your listener? Try logging there.

Besides that why you you firing custom events? You can just listen straight to the select event in your controller.

**Edit**
I've just looked at one of my projects and we use the select event. So try logging in your initial listener where you fire your custom event.

Comment: The 'select' event is fired - writing to the console proves this. I did check that as part of debugging. Just removed that code for clarity in this post.

Yes - I can just listen straight to the select event, but I am doing it this way to debug - so I can write to the console like you suggested to be sure it is fired. I've also tried the scope:this suggestion from mistaecko with no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 'this' keyword in your second event listener is not set correctly.

Your button event listener works correctly because by using the 'handler' property to register   the listener ExtJs binds the function automatically to the current button object.

This is what the docs say about `Ext.button.Button#scope`:

> scope : Object
>   The scope (this reference) in which the handler and toggleHandler is executed. Defaults to this Button.

However, when registering listeners using the 'listener' property one has to specify the 'scope' property otherwise the 'this' reference points to the global window object.

See [the docs for the listener property](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-addListener)

In your case the best approach might be to register the listener like this:

```
this.campaignsComboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', { .. });
this.campaignComboBox.on( 'select', 
                          function() { this.fireEvent('testEvent'); }, 
                          /* 'scope' aka 'this' reference: */ this.campaignsComboBox);
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nXSAN/

Another way to get the correct reference in your listener is to make use of the first function parameter, which is actually a reference to the ComboBox object (in case of the `select` event):

```
    function(cmp) { cmp.fireEvent('testEvent'); }
```

**UPDATE2**
Sencha (or my provider) is having troubles with Sencha's CDN, so here an 'offline' version.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Extjs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs-4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs-4.1.1/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.define('App.view.prospects.Filter', {
            alias: 'widget.prospectsfilter',
            extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
            itemId: 'prospectsfilter',

            height: 50,
            width: 100,
            layout: 'fit',


            initComponent: function() {

                this.combo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
                    itemId: 'campaignsComboBox',
                    text: 'Test',

                    queryMode: 'local',
                    displayField: 'name',
                    valueField: 'name',

                    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
                        fields: ['name'],
                        data: [ ['entry1'], ['entry2'], ['entry3'] ]
                    }),

                    listeners: {
                        select: function() {
                            this.fireEvent('testEvent')
                        }
                    }
                });

                this.items = [
                    this.combo
                ];

                this.callParent(arguments);
            }
        });

        Ext.define('App.controller.ProspectsFilter', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

            init: function() {
                this.control({
                    'prospectsfilter #campaignsComboBox': {
                        'testEvent': function() {
                            console.log('Found #campaignsComboBox!');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Ext.application({
            name: 'App',
            autoCreateViewport: false,
            launch: function() {
                Ext.create('App.view.prospects.Filter', { renderTo: Ext.getBody() });
                var controller = Ext.create('App.controller.ProspectsFilter', { application: this });
                controller.init(this);
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I realize this is likely a scope issue, but I've already tried your suggestion (I did again just now with no difference), as well as adding the scope:this to the listener definition. No difference. I am still stuck.

Comment: I am still not 100% convinced that you've got the 'this' reference correct. Adding `scope: this` to your listener config above would actually set the 'this' reference to the 'Ext.form.Panel' instance. Can you see why?

Comment: oops. just noticed my code example makes the very same mistake: the scope should be set to `this.campaignComboBox` and not `this` which points to the form panel.

Comment: Yes. It would add the reference to the form panel. When trying that, I change the selector in the controller to be 'prospectsfilter' only, without the reference to the '#campaignsComboBox' itemId. No difference. The selectors fail to work.

Comment: Oh - I tried adding 'scope: this.campaignsComboBox as well, but that made no difference either. I think the issue may be that the view is in a subfolder, hence the definition as 'App.view.prospects.Filter' instead of 'App.view.prospectsFilter', and maybe I need to do something different because of that?

Comment: Did you see my other edits? I provided a working example as a jsfiddle. Also, I suggested that you can avoid the scope/this reference problem by using the ComboBox reference that is passed in as the first argument.

Comment: Yes. I saw your JSFiddle. I have tried all suggestions from you and others. Nothing works. I realize the JSFiddle works, but so do other similar sections of my app. It is either a typo in my code, or the JSFiddle is not an 'apples to apples' comparison.

Comment: I should add - your JSFiddle only shows the selectors working for the button. I have that working. That is not the issue. It is getting the selectors to work for the ComboBox that is the problem.

Comment: I updated the answer to add a working example for the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: you are correct the # can be attributed to itemId attribute as well - I didn't know that so thanks! Yes, the use of ID property is not recommended.

So I took your combo box and placed it into my jsfiddle example and had it working correctly. I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, perhaps you are using an outdated library version?
Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/etxwP/  Click create button to show the form - sorry old example.

**EDIT 2:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/4JubT/6/ you have a dependency issue and cannot use ext-all with all-classes.

Comment: Nope. the # symbol can prefix an itemId. Besides, that component works as expected. It is the ComboBox I can't get the selectors working for. Working with id properties is bad practice. From [the ExtJS Guides](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) we see "An itemId or id must be prefixed with a #."

Comment: Let me get this straight: you are including an ext-all and classes-all in your project? There is no need for that. You are going to be defining classes twice and your app wont work properly.

Comment: No. The all-classes.js file is completely different from the ext-all.js file. The all-classes.js file contains all the 'Desktop/Webtop' classes.

Comment: Not completely different at all - I looked at the example and it combines code specific to webtop demo and some of the framework classes. There is still dependency on the core but you should not include ext-all with that file. The core ext dependency is still there see this forked fiddle from yours: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/4JubT/6/

Comment: Not sure I follow. The files are completely different. Even the ExtJS demo includes them both. [See image here.](http://i.imgur.com/W6PWv.png) Ah! I see what may be the confusion. I stated ext-all.js when I should have said ext.js.

Comment: Correct. And if you select an EXtJS 4.1.1 Framework in jsfiddle you will get ext-all.js - which of course causes the behavior you observed